# C++ Impossible pointer behavior

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I'm writing something like Java, and I have problem with pointer (- - )
I have a struct:

```
struct _lnHeader32
{ unsigned char signature[2]; //LN
  unsigned char architecture;
  unsigned int length; //Without _lnHeader
  unsigned int lnHeaderLength;
  unsigned char permissions;
  unsigned char typeOfExecutable;
  unsigned int flowSegment;
  unsigned int dataSegment;
  unsigned int loaderSegment;
  unsigned int cleanerSegment;
  unsigned int errorSegment;
  unsigned int exportTable;
  unsigned int importTable;
  unsigned int authenticationTable; //Encrypt it with GPG.
  unsigned int loaderTable;
};
```

I load executable, which is in little-endian, by using std::fstream:

```
lnFile.open(argv[1], std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
if (false == lnFile.is_open())
 throw (unableToOpen);
lnSize = getFileSize(lnFile);
lnImage = new (std::nothrow) unsigned char [lnSize];
if (0 == lnImage)
 throw (noMem);
lnFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(lnImage), lnSize); //#1 Possible mistake?
if (!lnFile)
 throw (unableToRead);
lnFile.close();
```

Then I point _lnHeader32* to allocated lnImage:

```
lnHeader32 = reinterpret_cast<_lnHeader32*>(lnImage);
```

At final I print whole struct by two methods:

```
//Method 1
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(lnImage) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(lnImage+2) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(lnImage+3) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(lnImage+7) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(lnImage+11) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(lnImage+12) << "\n\n";

//Method 2    
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&lnHeader32->signature) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&lnHeader32->architecture) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&lnHeader32->length) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&lnHeader32->lnHeaderLength) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&lnHeader32->permissions) << "\n";
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&lnHeader32->typeOfExecutable) 
                                                                  << "\n\n";
```

It gives Me output like:

```
0xe8b260
0xe8b262
0xe8b263 <---
0xe8b267
0xe8b26b
0xe8b26c

0xe8b260
0xe8b262
0xe8b264 <--- Should be 0xe8b263 | Here starts problem
0xe8b268
0xe8b26c
0xe8b26d
```

It prints well lnHeader32's fields by using first method, but I prefer to use second method. I calculated everything few times. Why it is happening?
Executable is generated by compiler done in perl, has it any influence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_padding

Comment: Using nothrow new, only to check the result for null and then throw is a real WTF?

Comment: Now everything is fine. Thank You, Oli Charlesworth.

Comment: `if( false == data.isOpen() )` Arghhh, thats the most horrible boolean condition I have ever seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to padding (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_padding) your struct actually looks like this:

```
struct _lnHeader32 {
  unsigned char signature[2]; //LN
  unsigned char architecture;
  unsigned char PADDING[1];//so next member will be aligned by 4
  unsigned int length; //Without _lnHeader
  unsigned int lnHeaderLength;
  unsigned char permissions;
  unsigned char typeOfExecutable;
  unsigned char PADDING[2];//so next member will be aligned by 4
  unsigned int flowSegment;
  unsigned int dataSegment;
  unsigned int loaderSegment;
  unsigned int cleanerSegment;
  unsigned int errorSegment;
  unsigned int exportTable;
  unsigned int importTable;
  unsigned int authenticationTable; //Encrypt it with GPG.
  unsigned int loaderTable;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Fields of C++ types in memory are not necessary continuous, there are certain rules controlling when the compiler introduce padding between the fields.

Fields of different types are usually aligned at a pre-determined boundary. In this case
`char` has the size of 1 byte, and it is 1-aligned, `int` has the size of 4 bytes and it is 4-aligned. (You can find more details about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)).

So your struct is going to look like this in memory

```
0: signature[0]
1: signature[1]
2: architecture
3: PADDING!
4: first byte of length
...
```

And you are getting an incorrect value for the length field because of the padding.

I would advise you against reading raw data into memory and reinterpret_casting it to a certain type. This could be very dangerous, because you can hardly be sure how your compiler aligns your type in memory.

A far more secure solution would be to create a helper function, like

```
_lnHeader32 readLnHeader32(const char* binary);
```

and in this function read the fields of the `_lnHeader32` struct one by one from the binary stream read from the file.